# find expectation of non-negative integer valued RV from generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions, expectation

How can we find $E\left(X\right)$ and $E\left(X^{2}\right)$ if all
we have is that $G\left(s\right)$ is the generating function for
X, which takes non-negative integer values.

I know $E\left(X\right)$ = $G'\left(1\right)$ and $G\left(s\right)=$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}s^{i}P\left(X=i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}s^{i}f(i)$
but how can I take the derivative?

Comment: Do you have an expression for $G(s)$?

Comment: No, no expression is given. Is is even possible to simplify the expectation further without $G\left(s\right)$ or an explicit function for $f\left(i\right)$?

Comment: If you know NOTHING about the function than "the derivative of the function evaluated at 1" is your final answer.

Comment: You cannot expect to get information from nothing.

Answer (score 1):

$E\left(X\right)$ = $G'\left(1\right)$ and $G\left(s\right)=$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}s^{i}P\left(X=i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}s^{i}f(i)$

$G'(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}is^{i-1}f\left(i\right)$

$G''(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\left(i-1\right)s^{i-2}f\left(i\right)$

$G''(1) = \mathrm{E}(X^{2}) - \mathrm{E}(X)$

Just take the derivative with respect to s and you can play with my expression for $G''(s)$ (by splitting it into two summations) if you want to see the algebra.

Answer (score -1):

$G''(1)=E(x^2)-E(x)$
then $E(x^2)=G''(1)+G'(1)$